# how do I restrict users to only one post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making a friend finder application. I want to restrict the users to only one post. Here's what I have so far:

```
router.post("/", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    //get data from form and add to friendfinder array
    var rank = req.body.rank;
    var discord = req.body.discord;
    var valorantid = req.body.valorantid;
    var author  = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username,
    };
    var newFriend = {rank:rank, discord:discord, valorantid:valorantid, author:author};
        //create a new friend finder entry

    Lookinglist.create(newFriend, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to frinedfinder page
            res.redirect("friendfinder");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a route for `/friendfinder`?
if yes, use this

`res.redirect("friendfinder");`